# LogOut button creates back button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, uibutton

I created a button in my `UITableViewController` as a Left Bar Button Item to log the current user out and segue and to the login `ViewController`.

The problem is that tapping it creates a back button on the login `ViewController` and user can come back to the previous view.

[image]

Comment: can you display that what you write for it?

Comment: In VIewWillApper Hide your NavigatoinBar.

Comment: Your architecture is wrong. You should not be making a segue to the login controller, that way the navigation stack won't be empty and you'll have all your view controllers from before the logout event. When you press the logout button, what you could do is: Instantiate a new view controller (the login one) and set the view controllers of the navigation controller as only the login one. Are you using swift or objective-C? I can show you how to do it. You can also (and it's the best way) pop to the root view controller (self.navigationController.popToRootViewController)

Comment: Hello. I am coding in swift. My initial view controller is Login viewController. When you log in, it segues you to "Wybierz Miasto" TableViewController, which is connected to navigation controller. "Wybierz Miasto" has a left bar button, which log you out. @FlavioSilverio

Comment: use  **self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)** for pop a viewcontroller in swift

Comment: @NitinGohel Okay, thank you. Should I make a segue from the button to the ViewController and put this code in performSegue method or make just the button action with the code with segue?

Comment: put this in button IBAction

Comment: @NitinGohel I did it and deleted the segue and nothing happens. It doesn't take me to login ViewController.

Comment: i just create a demo wait i edit my answer

Comment: @Michal check my updated answer with demo code hope now you get what i said. and yes this is not copied or other's answer lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your architecture is wrong. You should not be making a segue to the login controller, that way the navigation stack won't be empty and you'll have all your view controllers from before the logout event. When you press the logout button, what you could do is:

If it's the Root view controller:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

If not:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *login = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[login] animated:true];
```

Comment: Hello, thanks. It works. I code in swift, but I managed to transform your code. Unfortunately, when it logs me out and takes me back to the login viewcontroller it shows the top bar with the title of the controller. Should I hide it using: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true
?

Comment: If you do that, make sure to make it visible again on viewWillDisappear, then it'll work fine.

Comment: but why should I do that if I don't need it anyway?

Comment: If you don't need it you can just go to storyboards and explicitly set that you want it hidden.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Usually application flow works like we set a `loginViewController` as a `rootviewcontroller` of our application and we are push a `nextViewController` as per our application flow and its need. but in your case you are push a `loginViewController` again at a logout time instead you need to `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` code

So use following code on your logout button clickEvnet:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I am not suggest to use hide BackBarButton and do any other trick you can simply do by put a `popToRootViewControllerAnimated`

If you are doing code in swift you could use following code:

```
 self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

**UPDATE**
I just create an example for you. You can download from following url:

https://github.com/nitingohel/swiftSeque

Its output like following:

[image]

Comment: @NitinGohel I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I didn't managed to do it with the "poptoroot". Instead I used self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false) in viewWillAppear method and it worked for me.

Comment: @Michal that alright but this is not good practice you have to think about. because in each time logout you push a new object of loginviewcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

Your flow of navigation controller of app is wrong i think. Login view controller should be rootview controller of navigation controller or it should be initial view controller. You have another viewcontroller something like `Wybierz miasto` !! It shouldn't like this.

You can call

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

from any view controller of navigation stack to go rootview controller. (i.e. logout).

If you must require flow like this then you can hide and show backbutton like,

```
  self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; //NO for show
```

If you want to hide navigation bar for particular view controller you can do like

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
  }

 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
 }
```

**Update in swift as asked in comment**

```
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

and

```
   self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

and

```
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = true
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.hidden = false
}
```

Avoid mistakes in swift if any! Not much familiar with swift!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: great keep it up i dont know what's new in your answer and how did you get +

Comment: Hello, thanks. Sorry, I did not specify that I code in Swift. My initial view controller is Login viewController. When you log in, it segues you to "Wybierz Miasto" TableViewController, which is connected to navigation controller. "Wybierz Miasto" has a left bar button, which log you out. Is it something wrong with this?

Comment: then you should change it's title to logout or you should hide it and take another button to your desired place and call `poptorootviewcontroller` from that button click

Comment: @Lion Thank you very much. Should I put the "hideButton" and "popToRoot" code into the log out action and should I still use segue and the performSegue method?

Comment: You shoud hide button in viewdid load and you shoud use poptoroot in action of logout button

Comment: @Lion I did it and deleted the segue and nothing happens. It doesn't take me to login ViewController.

Comment: don't delete segue. segue is required !!

Answer (score 1):

Dont do tricks like hiding `navigationBarItem`.It is not suggested. instead of that call

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

always keep login screen as `RootViewController`

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your login view controller `viewWillAppear` method to hide back button

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

and to hide navigationbar

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Thanks. It works. There is no back button anymore, but unfortunately the navigation bar is still there. What can I do ?

Comment: Use this code [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];@Michal

Answer (score 0):

use this code it works for you:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for removing the back button only.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }
```

hope this will work.